# Merging [images] [photos] [pictures] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Why do we need 3 different tags for this? Is there any difference?
I understand that the terms might be a little bit different by definition, but I don't think it matters when tagging questions on SuperUser. Also, there's already [photography](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photography).

- [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images)
- [photos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photos)
- [pictures](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pictures)

Comment: Images might be system images (ISOs, etc.).

Comment: @slhck Ah, I see. Anyway, as for now, it's not the way people use this tag. `[images]` tag description: `Questions tagged with this tag can refer to graphical images, e.g. a .jpg or .gif file or system snapshots, which are also called "images".`

Comment: Photos are pictures taken with a camera. Questions about red eye removal probably are related to photos. Questions about SVG probably aren't.

Comment: @DanielBeck What about merging `[images]` and `[pictures]`? Also, I think we should add a clear tag description to explain the purpose of each one of them and the differences between them.

Comment: @tempy [tag:images] has been on by agenda since long, problem is as the wiki says, it's got too much of all to go for mass retags.

Comment: @slhck Personally, I tend to refer to those kinds of images as “disk images” and not simply “images”.

Comment: @slhck Just a reminder :)

Comment: I'm still a little unsure with regard to images needing disambiguation, and the subtle difference between photos and pictures. Not every picture is a photo.

Comment: @slhck I thought merging `[pictures]` into `[images]` and leaving only `[images]` and `[photos]` would be okay.

Comment: Before doing so we'd need to get all system images out of the images tag though :)

Answer (score 4):

I think just a tag clean up of Images, and merge Photos and Pictures. Or, option 2, is to make [system-image], [cd-image], [disk-image] all for [image] (not my first choice)

Comment: [disk-image] is unambiguous, "images" meaning two things definitely has to go. Agreed on merging the other two