# Girl, you're a mess: [images] needs a makeover

Tags: discussion, status-planned, tag-cleanup-request

This is a plea to add [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) to the tag-cleanup agenda. It was discussed tangentially in the comments on [this meta question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5849/76571) from over two years ago, but no firm plans were made to attack this massive (1,447 questions as of now) ambiguous tag.

The first step would be to come to consensus on how the tag is to be used. Since [disk-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-image) has been created, I assume questions related to image processing and pictures/graphics should retain the [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) tag, while all others should be retagged.

Next would be to rewrite the counterproductive tag wiki that props up the ambiguity of the tag. Include usage guidance and redirect people with questions about disk images to use [disk-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-image) instead.

The final step would be the mass cull/retagging of disk-image questions wrongly tagged with [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images).

Who's with me?

Comment: Leaving it there would simply allow the problem to come back in time.  There are alternatives such as [tag:image-editing] or [tag:vector-graphics] which have more clear meanings.

Comment: -1 for not writing a witty question title: you could have said something like "Let's bring [[tag:images]] into focus". :-)

Comment: @Scott, to me original title "Plea to disambiguate [images]" makes alot more sense. Although the word `tag` in it would have helped even more.

Comment: @akostadinov No. Witty titles are a must. See: [plugins](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8400/130931), [skipping](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8709/130931), [utilization](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8655/130931), [columns](http://meta.superuser.com/q/9117/130931), [dual-core/quad-core/multi-core](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8869/130931), etc.

Comment: @scott, ah, didn't know what witty mean and didn't see your smiley :) given your examples now I can fully agree with you, it's a loss

Comment: Is the new title witty enough?

Comment: @Excellll not the best, but it's much better

Comment: This is still happening, only a couple days ago someone asked a question with this tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would vote for burninate [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) and replace it for their peers, [image-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-editing), [disk-image](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-image), etc. in a way that [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) doesn't exist, since it's a term that loosely apply to many things. But to fulfill this, it would be necessary to blacklist [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) for the disambiguation to be more effective.

Comment: What would one use for a question about image files that isn't necessarily related to image editing?

Comment: @Twisty image presentation? Image categorization? Image sharing? Virtually any verb you can think of with any kind of data just that instead of X, images.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. When someone tries to use a blacklisted tag, are they given guidance as to better alternatives?

Comment: @Twisty only if Shog want to tease someone.